# IE11 partially crashes

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, crash, internet-explorer-11

I’m running an older website for Internet Explorer, using VBScript and an ActiveX object (RAPI, C++) developed by our team. Since IE11 does not support VBScript we use the emulate tag, ,  in the config file. We also use iFrames (not displaying cross domain web pages).

This setup works fine in IE 8, 9, 10 but not in IE11. The problem is that after our ActiveX component has displayed a modal dialogue IE crashes. It’s not closed down or restarted but it gets these symptoms:

1. Drop down lists doesn’t expand. They are populated  and you can scroll all values using the arrow keys but it will not expand.
2. You cannot start Developer Tools after this point. (F12)
3. You cannot open internet settings.
4. View source is opened in notepad instead of the built in viewer.
5. You cannot leave the website by typing www.microsoft.com (or other web site) in the address field. You can still go to other pages in our own site but not leave our site.

After this crash it’s still possible to use our web site with full functionality, except for the drop down lists. The symptoms in the list above remains as long as the tab is open.

Anyone with similar experience?

Regards Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Just recently, IE11 introduced the out-of-date ActiveX control blocking. It might and probably be the cause of the issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/10/14/october-2014-updates-and-a-preview-of-changes-to-out-of-date-activex-control-blocking.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn761713.aspx

I also suppose your ActiveX control is signed since by default IE does not download unsigned ActiveX controls.

I know this is not the exact answers you need but its more of diagnostic steps for us to take to determine the root cause by checking your IE11 settings

Comment: Hi Roman! Yes, the ActiveX controls are signed. I have been aware of our issue since late summer of 2014 so It's some time before Microsoft released the "Out of date ActiveX blocking" I guess? I have never seen any IE messages saying that our ActiveX controls are out of date. /BR Andreas